How to best fill or seal top of cinderblock walls?
As part of a remodel we are re-covering the walls in our garage, which sit on a concrete cinderblock foundation/footing of sorts. The problem is that mice seem to be tunnelling through from beneath/outside somehow:

I had already vacuumed most of it up and also down into that hole by the pipe before I took the picture, but the block was full and overflowing with a whole pile of dirt spilled out onto the floor behind the freezers along that wall!
So it seems these walls might be a little bit too unfinished in their current state? I live and let live but I'd like to encourage the wildlife to stay outside these walls as much as practical.
I thought about just getting some cans of Great Stuff, but it's two 24 foot walls and seems like I could end up needing a lot of cans. We will be having some sprayfoam insulation done elsewhere, so perhaps I could get an estimate from them to do it in bulk if a foam fill is even a good idea here.
Otherwise should we just fill these in with concrete? And if so, should we do it completely (like try to completely fill all the rows of bricks from bottom to top) with concrete and even rebar while we're at it? Or maybe just pour sand or even just stuff some cardboard or batten down in each hole and sort of just mort in some cement/concrete to sort of cap off just the top few inches of the top row holes?
We've also considered just simply covering it with a wooden sill of sorts (which we might do regardless) but I suspect the mice could still squeeze through along that. Perhaps there's some sort of flexible foam/rubber sealing that would work as sort of a "gasket" underneath and not break down or get chewed through the years?
Basically just wondering if there's a bog-standard way to handle this we should do, or at least what the most practical option is here.

Cement will stop most animals.  Any foam will not.  A few inches of cement is all that is needed to stop animals.  Filling the blocks all the way will add strength to the wall.

For just the top, metal flashing will work also for animals.  Less messy than cement.

As a fast temporary fix, filling the cavity with steel wool and then spraying foam into its lock it in place is something few rodents are going to want to chew through. But, yes, concrete is probably more effective and just as easy

"I thought about just getting some cans of Great Stuff" Mice will just chew through that.  It can block air which might help keep attractive smells from the mice.  However, if you try to fill a mouse-sized or larger hole with it, the mice will be able to get through it if they want to do so.

And if you don't want to have to mix up so much concrete (grout), you can fill up to within about 3" with spray foam, and just top it with the concrete.

Concrete is normally used in a horizontal application for its compressive strength. Concrete contains cement, sand, aggregate (usually stones), and water.
Mortar is normally used to seal brick and block. It is not so much for structural strength as for sealing. Mortar is like concrete without the aggregate.
The cheapest easiest thing might be to mix up mortar fairly loose and pour it into the cavities in the wall. (The bricklayers normally "slush" the block on both sides of a door frame with mortar to add some strength and then they add re-bar for strength. Strength is not needed here but the sealing power of mortar will help.)
The mortar will discourage the mice from penetrating the wall and then some judicially located traps will eliminate the bold ones. Peanut butter works better than cheese.
Good Luck!
